# Handle navigation in android mvvm

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

I am building an android application and I am not sure about how to implement navigation in MVVM architecture. 
The first approach I took is to bind the on click event button to a function in the ViewModel that does some logic if necessary(for example some data validation) and then fires a LiveData event(that tells the view to navigate to different screen) to a view that observes the ViewModel.

```xml
<button android:id="@+id/btnId"
        android:onClick="@{(v) -> myViewModel.onSaveClick()}"
        .../>
```

```java
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val saveNavigation = MutableLiveData<Event<Customer>>()
    val errorMessage = MutableLiveData<Event<String>>()

    fun onSaveClick() {
        if (validateCustomer(customer)) {
            repository.save(customer)
            saveNavigation.value = Event(customer)
        }
        else
            errorMessage.value = Event("error")
    }
}

class View : Fragment() {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        //observe event protects from re-reading the value on screen rotation
        myViewModel.saveNavigation.observeEvent(this) {
             findNavController().navigate(CustomerViewDirections
                    .actionCustomerInfoToCustomerBalanceHistory(it))
        }

        myViewModel.errorMessage.observeEvent(this) { toast(it) }
    }
}
```

The second approach is that the view registers to an onClickListener and actively calls the ViewModel logic function(for example validation) and only after that the view does the navigation

```java
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    fun save() : Status {
        if (validateCustomer(customer)) {
            repository.save(customer)
            return Status.OK
        }
        else
            return Status.Error //or some string message
    }
}

class View : Fragment() {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        btnId.setOnClickListener {
            if (myViewModel.save() == Status.OK) 
                findNavController().navigate(CustomerViewDirections
                    .actionCustomerInfoToCustomerBalanceHistory(myViewModel.customer))
            else
                toast("error")
        }
    }
}
```

Which of these two ways is better for the MVVM architecture or maybe there is another option to go with?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a Navigator interface that gets injected to your ViewModels using your dependency injection of choice. You then implement that interface in a component that handles the navigation. You would then navigate using the methods from that Navigator interface.

For instance,

```
interface Navigator {
    fun navigateToSettings()
}

class NavigatorImpl : Navigator {
    override fun navigateToSettings() {
        TODO()
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I obtain a reference to the `NavController` inside `NavigatorImpl`?  I use `view.findNavController().navigate(actionId)` inside my views (which awkwardly reroute from the ViewModel back to the view inside a clickListener)